# how to read XML using XLinq and bind it to Combo Box?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

Hi I am trying to read XML File using XLinq and binding the values into Combo Box:-

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("abc.xml");
 var res = from c in xmlDoc.Element("Clients").Descendants("Client")
           select c;

 cmb1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
 cmb1.DataSource = res;
 cmb1.DisplayMember = "Name";
 cmb1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

My XMl structure is something like this:-

```
<Clients>
    <Client>
        <ID>-1</ID>
        <Name>--Select--</Name>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>A</Name>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>B</Name>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>C</Name>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Name>D</Name>
    </Client>
</Clients>
```

But somehow i am getting errors. Pleas help

Error is:-

```
System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value)
```

Comment: What errors? Detailed errormsg with the line please. And I'm not inclined to put much time in a question where "the XMl structure is something like this".

Comment: @Henk: Thanks but sounds like XML structure is bad. Please recommend me the right structure, coz its changeable.

Comment: @Henk: Also update my question (added error details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query produces an `IEnumerable<XElement>` , that doesn't give you the properties you want.

```
   // not tested
   var res = from c in xmlDoc.Element("Clients").Descendants("Client")
   select new { Name=c.Element("Name").Value, ID = c.Element("ID").Value };

   ...
   cmb1.DataSource = res.ToList();
```

The ID will be a string.

Comment: Please now i am more curious to know the right XML format. (As you mentioned in your comments above)

Comment: Ya Thanks. Its working. :) but what is your preferred XML Format?

Comment: My comment wasn't about your format but about the "something like" in a question.

Comment: Oh. Sorry Henk. Thanks anyways